# Как на андроид реализовать подсчет времени, проведенного в приложении?

Tags: java, android

Как на андроид реализовать подсчет времени, проведенного в приложении?

Comment: подозреваю что также как и везде. запоминать время инициализации приложения и сравнивать с текущим.

Comment: а как же быть с выходом из приложения? неужели обновлять каждую секунду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте класс, который будет сохранять в SharedPreferences время прошедшее между вызовами методов onPause и onResume активити.

```
public class CheckTime
{
    private final static String LOG = CheckTimeToAds.class.getSimpleName();

    public final static String PREF_KEY_IN_APP_PERIOD = "inAppPeriod";

    private Context ctx;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private long timeOnResume;

    private UncaughtExceptionHandler deafultUncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    private UncaughtExceptionHandler myUncaughtExceptionHandler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        public Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler = deafultUncaughtExceptionHandler;

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
        {
            String errMsg = (ex.getLocalizedMessage() != null) ? ex.getLocalizedMessage() : "NULL message";
            Log.e(LOG, "uncaughtException: " + errMsg);
            onPause();
            if (oldHandler != null)
            {
                oldHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
            }
        }
    };

    public static long getInAppPeriod(Context ctx)
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return pref.getLong(PREF_KEY_IN_APP_PERIOD, (45L * 60L * 1000L));
    }

    public CheckTimeToAds(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        this.init();
    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        timeOnResume = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(myUncaughtExceptionHandler);
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        long timeOnPause = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long inAppPeriod = timeOnPause - this.timeOnResume;

        long alreadyStoredInAppPeriod = this.pref.getLong(PREF_KEY_IN_APP_PERIOD, 0L);

        inAppPeriod += alreadyStoredInAppPeriod;
            this.pref.edit().putLong(PREF_KEY_IN_APP_PERIOD, inAppPeriod).commit();

        this.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(deafultUncaughtExceptionHandler);
    }

    private void setUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler handler)
    {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler);
    }

    private void init()
    {
        this.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(myUncaughtExceptionHandler);       
    }
}
```

Далее в каждой активити в onCreate инициализируйте экземпляр этого класс и вызовите его соответствующие методы в onResume и onPause методах. Так вы сможете измерить время активной жизни приложения. В т.ч. если оно упадёт в этом промежутке.

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity
{
    final private static String LOG = ActivityMain.class.getSimpleName();

    CheckTime checkTimeAds;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.e(LOG, "ActivityMain onCreate called");
        this.checkTimeAds = new CheckTime(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        Log.e(LOG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
        this.checkTimeAds.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        Log.e(LOG, "onPause");
        this.checkTimeAds.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Получить проведённое в приложении время можно будет так:

```
CheckTime.getInAppPeriod(context);
```

---

Код старый, не идеальный, с кучей ограничений и нужно его полностью переписать,  но он работает

Comment: brilliant! perfect!